# Embedding an interactive google calendar in website for multiple groups of users

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am thinking to embed google calendar in my website to achieve the following and was wondering if this is doable in google calendar. Otherwise I have to go find another solution.

I have groups of users with one super user, and rest are regular users as follows:

- GroupA

  - Super User 1
  - Regular User 1
  - Regular user 2
  - etc
- Group B

  - Super User 2
  - Regular User 3
  - Regular User 4
  - etc

Each group have their own calendar. Users in each group can not see the other group's calendar. Only able to see their own group's calendar.

Super users of each group have all access to the calendar (add, modify, delete) and have the ability to control how much access regular users have in their group. (read only? read/write etc)

All users are registered to my website, therefore I am thinking to use only one google calendar account (my own account) to create a calendar for each group. Which leads to a question of authenticating my website to google's API. I need the authentication process to be automatic, hidden away from the user and be done on the server side.

My site is built using PHP/Mysql

Q1:
I have tried the Javascript client library provided by google, however it require the user to type in username/password to log into google so that the authentication (OAuth2) process can work. As mentioned in previous paragraph, I only want the user's to log into my website, they do not need to login again into google account. This should be done on serverside.

I even went as far to create a login form with information prepopulated (hidden from the user, the username/password will be visible in "view page source") and send the request to https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth, and make the form automatic submit once the user successfully login into my website. However this causes cross domain issues.

Q2:
I may potentially have 10's of thousands of groups registered on my website. each group may have couple hundred users. Can one single google account create that many calendars?

Q3:
Once the calendar is embedded into my website, it seems to be read-only. Is it possible to make it interactive so super users in each group can add/delete/modify events?

Any ideas/suggestions is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar use case but struggling with the Google documentation. Need to create group calendars and assign users to them. Links or pointers to the resources you found would be create. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No answers?  It seems like your question is straightforward.  If I understand correctly, you want to access calendars from several Google accounts/users.  Each user needs to authorize this access, but they only need to do so once.  You could generate these requests and send them out via email, for example.  When the user grants permission, Google forwards a *grant code* to your specified callback_uri.  The *grant code* is extremely volatile.  It's used to request a token from Google that apparently lasts indefinitely.  So there's no requirement that users continually log into Google.

In Google's calendar/simple.php example.  The token is stored as a SESSION variable.  Even though the token is persistent, the SESSION variable is not.  Users have to grant authorization every time the SESSION variable expires.  Storing persistent data in a volatile variable is absurd and probably gives the wrong impression about the OAuth2 token mechanism.

I spent a lot of time writing documentation that I couldn't find anywhere else.  Please take a look if you think it might help:  http://www.tqis.com/eloquency/googlecalendar.htm

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't possible in Google Calendar.

If you're looking to support thousands of groups and each group needs it's own calendar, then you're saying that you'd need thousands of calendars with access control and you'd need authentication to the calendar to be transparent.